Fastener to secure decorative wall hook help


I have this decorative wall hook that I want to use for hanging my keys, but I'm having some trouble figuring out how to attach it securely. The loop for hanging it is located behind the metal flower portion on the hook, and I also don't want the hook to swing back and forth every time I put my keys on or take them off.
I'm not sure how to drive a screw in behind the flower, and I'm also not sure how to secure the hook portion so it doesn't swing. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to properly attach it to the wall? Is there some type of screw, nail or another material that would work for this purpose?
Thanks in advance for your help!

is the wall a drywall type

Yes, this is drywall.

I've dealt with these decorative hooks before. They look nice but are very impractical. Most are designed to just be mounted with a picture hook, screw or nail. If you use a screw or nail you install that first leaving a gap with head of the screw/nail and the wall, then you hang the hook.
However this makes them easy to bump off and there is no way to stop them from swinging which will eventually damage your wall. My solution was to mount them to a board using a screw for the top and then use a cable U clamp to secure the lower part of the hook to prevent any swinging.

I then mounted the board with two screws into the drywall.
